# Load a different form layout on spinner selection

Tags: java, android, android-layout

On opening the activity, the user chooses an option from a spinner.  I have the spinner working and I can successfully read the `onItemSelected` listener from the spinner.  However, after the user clicks the spinner, I'd like to load a different form layout below the spinner; based on their choice.  Can I store the different layouts in the same XML file, and then just call them based on their ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use different layout on a layout.See how to Inflate Layout.See [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html) link for android layout Inflate.In your main layout create two linearLayout.add your spinner in the first layout.And in the second layout add various layout according to your choice using LayoutInflater